# java Unreachable catch block for SQLException

Tags: java, sql, exception, sqlexception

I want to catch `SQLException` on the **try-catch block** of `Foo` method and here is my code which is not working actually;

```
public int Foo() {
    try {
        DB.delete("table", "fname=" + name);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
    }
}

public int delete(String table, String conditions) {
    int updatedRow = 0;
    try {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM " + table + " SET " + " WHERE " + conditions;
        updatedRow = SPM_Database.opeStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("message" + ex);
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return updatedRow;
}
```

I've got error from catch-block inside Foo() method in my IDE which is;

> Unreachable catch block for `SQLException`

This exception is never thrown from the try-block. Why I cannot use the try-catch block? Is that I need to throw `SQLException` from delete() function or any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `delete` method can never throw a `SQLException`, since it doesn't declare it in a `throws` clause. Therefore, your catch clause in `Foo` is unreachable.

You don't need to throw `SQLException` from the `delete` method, but you also don't need to surround the call to `delete` with a try block and you don't need to catch `SQLException`.

Comment: is it good practice to catch SQLException in lower level or higher level? I mean in delete() or the place I call delete()?

Comment: @BufBills It depends on how you are going to handle it. If you just log the exception, it doesn't really matter where you catch it. If, on the other hand, you are going to try to recover, for example by retrying the delete operation, you should decide where is the best place to have the logic that performs the retry. It would probably make more sense to have this logic in a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

The methode **delete** needs to throw the exception so **Foo** can catch it.

```
public int delete(String table, String conditions)  throws  SQLException{
        int updatedRow = 0;

                String sql = "DELETE FROM " + table + " SET " + " WHERE " + conditions;
                updatedRow = SPM_Database.opeStmt.executeUpdate(sql);


        return updatedRow;
```

**Foo** remains as it is.

good luck!

Comment: is it good practice to catch SQLException in lower level or higher level? I mean in delete() or the place I call delete()?

Comment: In your case you should place catch in **Foo**, but in general it depends on the level of encapsulation that is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `throw` statement in your catch block after what you need to do is complete. And also you need to add `throws SQLException` on your method signature.

```
public int delete(String table, String conditions) throws SQLException { // signature is changed
    int updatedRow = 0;
    try {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM " + table + " SET " + " WHERE " + conditions;
        updatedRow = SPM_Database.opeStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("message"+ ex);
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;                                  //     <== ADD THIS LINE
    }

    return updatedRow;
}
```